# Encode multiple image to base64 Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, base64

I want to encode multiple image to base64 and save it to list String. Currently, Im using `multi_image_picker` packages. I already convert it to File.

```
List<File> _files = [
];


List<int> imageBytes = _files[index].readAsBytesSync();    
String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it helps you.
Just iterate '_files' and make a base64 data and add to List of String.

```
List<String> listBase64Images = []
for(var file in _files) {
   List<int> imageBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();    
   String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
   listBase64Images.add(base64Image);
}
```